# How to hide rows with variable data?

Tags: vba, excel

[top part of the worksheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ijkHb.png)[image]

very new to VBA and I'm trying to develop a macro to do some formatting. I have a variable amount of data (row wise, columns are the same) in my worksheet. After the last row of data, there are a bunch of blank white rows, and at the very bottom is a grey-shaded row. I want to hide all of the blank white rows in the middle, so that the grey-shaded row is then right under my last row with data in it.

Here is the code I have so far (note: Column I is the last column). Any help would be greatly appreciated. Right now, I am getting a "type mismatch" error for the "BeforeFinalRow = finalRow - 1" part, but I'm sure there's a lot more that's wrong with this code. Thanks in advance!

```
    Sub hide_rows()

      Dim BelowUsedData As Long
        BelowUsedData = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row + 1
      Dim RowBelowUsedData As Range
        RowBelowUsedData = Range("A" & BelowUsedData, "I" & BelowUsedData)
        Range("A1").Select
        Selection.End(xlDown).Select
      Dim finalRow As Range
        finalRow = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight))
      Dim BeforeFinalRow As Long
        BeforeFinalRow = finalRow - 1
        Rng = Range(Cells(RowBelowUsedData, "A"), Cells(BeforeFinalRow, "I")).Select
        Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

    End Sub
```

Comment: You have defined `finalRow as Range` and then you try to subtract a number from it, this is the type mismatch. If your data is in a continuous range, i.e. there are no completely blank columns or rows, you can easily get that range by `Range("A1").CurrentRegion`. Another thing - it is not a good idea to use `Select` and `Selection` as it may be unclear what it is, especially for a newbie. Can you post an image of the white and grey rows?

Comment: Thanks, jivko. I've read a lot about how it's not good to use select/selection but I'm not really sure how to go about it in a different way. Let me add a picture to the original post.

Comment: Will you be entering data in 1 row at a time or pasting bulk data in spanning multiple rows?

Comment: The worksheets come from running a tool in a different Excel sheet, so all of the data will already be there once the tool is run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could simplify this and hard code your bottom border cell into the code (Just change the value of `BottomBorder` in code)

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
Dim LRow As Long, BottomBorder As Long

LRow = ws.Range("B" & ws.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row
BottomBorder = 1006   'Change this if your bottom border changes

ws.Range(ws.Cells(LRow, 1), ws.Cells(BottomBorder, 1)).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

---

Another option is to use a `WorkSheet_Change` Event. This will only work if you are inputting data in one entry (row) at a time.

**To implement:** Hide all unused rows with the exception of 1! So if your last used cell is `B4`, hide `B6` down to `BottomBorder` which will leave `B5` as a white blank row where your next entry will go. Then paste the below code in the worksheet in `VBE`. Every time an entry is made in your blank row (`B5`) here, the macro will insert a new row keeping your current format.

This is dynamic so it will also look at the next blank row (After `B5`, `B6` will be your new target row)

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

Dim LRow As Long
LRow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Row

Application.EnableEvents = False
    If Target.Row = LRow - 1 And Target.Column = 2 Then
        Range("A" & LRow + 1).EntireRow.Insert (xlShiftUp)
    End If
Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! The first option worked like a charm. I'll definitely keep the second option in mind for future worksheets where we are inputting data one at a time. I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Sorry, also new to Stack Overflow. I was just reading through the quick summary of how the site works when I realized I needed to "accept" your comment. Thanks for the reminder :)

Answer (score 1):

On the photo it looks like the rows are not hidden but grey. The below code will find where the color changes and hide those white rows between the last row with data and the first grey cell:

```
Sub hide_rows()

Dim rngData As Range
Dim rngFirstCelltoHide As Range
Dim rngLastWhite As Range

Set rngData = Range("B1").CurrentRegion
Set rngFirstCelltoHide = rngData.Cells(rngData.Rows.Count, 1).Offset(1, 0)
Set rngLastWhite = rngFirstCelltoHide

Do Until rngLastWhite.Interior.Color <> rngLastWhite.Offset(1, 0).Interior.Color
    Set rngLastWhite = rngLastWhite.Offset(1, 0)
Loop

Range(rngFirstCelltoHide, rngLastWhite).EntireRow.Hidden = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this well thought out response! I should have shown a picture of the top of my worksheet as well. See picture posted to my original response and please ignore all the blah's - this is for work so not really sure if the data can be shown.

Can you please go more into detail about the "CurrentRegion" property?

Comment: Range("A1").CurrentRegion is the range that gets selected when you select A1 and press Ctrl+A. You can try it with different cells and see what happens. In your case probably you should get the CurrentRegion of B7 if that is constant in your worksheets.

Comment: Gotcha. B7 will be constant in the worksheets. However, the code does not change the worksheet when I use any number past B4. When using B1-B4, it is hiding a portion of the top blue part. I'll keep experimenting with the cell numbers but this is a really solid start and way better than my old code. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Revision to my "does not change the worksheet" comment - when I use cell B7 in this code, it does make one change: the last grey row is hidden. Everything else is the same.

Answer (score 0):

finalRow  is a range object.  That is why you get 'type error' when you subtract 1 from it.  Declare the variable as long and assign row number to it as follows:
finalRow = Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Row

Comment: So this has fixed that error, but now I am getting an error for the "Rng" variable at the bottom. I just realized I never set the dimensions for that variable - I tried setting the dimension to range but now it is giving me a type mismatch error for that. Any ideas?

Comment: When setting a reference, you should use `Set` so change it to `Set Rng`. And add `Option Explicit` at the top of your module. Without it, Rng is implicitly defined.

Comment: Thank you! Now I'm getting an "Object Required" error for Rng. Trying to work that out via Google now...